# Javascript: How to create dynamic tree/nested structure objects linked with dynamic drop downs values?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using Angular 2. 
I want to make a dynamic tree/nested objects with different names for each object as to push each within every child object.
For better understanding see below figure :

```
 var treeList = [];
 treeList = [
  {
    Id: "1", //Id of base parent
    childList: [ //child object of selected parent. 
      {
        Id: "2", //Id of child
        childList_1: [ // child object of selected child.
          {
            Id: "3", //Id of child
            childList_2: [ // child object of selected child.
                {
                    Id: "4", //Id of child
                    childList_3: [ // child object of selected child.
                    { //
                      //----goes on until selected drop down value doesn't have child 
                    }]
                }
            ]
          }]
          }
          ]
          }
          ]
```

As you can see the structure above, parent gets selected in first dropdown, and  as of that selection, respective **childList** populates the next dynamically created drop down. Again same process carries on until selected child doesn't have remaining child. 
I am confused with the implementation of this structured object, and please help me get logic for this.
And also how to maintain dynamic child list every time a new value is selected in dropdown.

For understanding more clearly, this is the tree :

```
    1 (selected parent)
    |
    |
    2 (1 child of selected parent)
  __|__
  |   |
  6   3 (child of selected child(i.e.2))
      |
      |
      4 (child of selected child(i.e.3))
      |
      |
      //Goes on...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am confused with the implementation of this structured object, and please help me get logic for this. And also how to maintain dynamic child list every time a new value is selected in dropdown ?
I need to structure the object same as above shown...dynamically